# How to return an array from a mongo document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am developing a MERN app. Here is my sample mongo object:

```
_id:60e07cdb99f119121d918269
count:Array
     0:Object
       date:2021-07-03T15:13:42.159+00:00
       count:1566
     1:Object
      date:2021-07-04T15:16:41.155+00:00
      count:1200
     3:Object
      date:2021-07-05T11:10:42.120+00:00
      count:903
goal:500
```

I want to get the list of count objects of a particular id. How to do it node express app?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation you can use [mongoose aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html%27) as shown below, please note that you will need to read and understand mongoose documentation to efficiently utilise the mongoose module

```
var tocomparegoal = 600;
yourmodelname.aggregate([
   {$match: {goal: {$gt: tocomparegoal}}},
   {$project:{count:"$count"}}
],((err,data) =>{
   if(err) {console.log(err}
   console.log(data
})
```

Also note that this assumes you have already setup your mongodb connection.

Comment: No, I want to retrieve the dates only.

Comment: The edit is a completely different question @axfg